# Buying Arduino Parts Different Manufacturers

Tags: arduino-mega, hardware

I'm looking to buy my first arduino kit. However I have a concern.

If my Arduino Mega is bought from one manufacturer, then can I buy shields or other parts from other manufacturers? Are there any incompatibility issues

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. In just the same way that you can buy a car from one manufacturer and bumper stickers from another.

That's the whole point of the Arduino platform - mix and match to make things -just like LEGO®.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the prompt reply.
if you do not mind, are there any basic components which are necessary for any project that I can ensure are in the kit I decide to buy

Comment: That's a hard question to answer without knowing what you want to do… You might start by taking a look at some of the Arduino starter kits at [Adafruit](http://adafruit.com) or some of the other vendors. They will give you a good idea of what you could use to get start with some general hacking and experimenting.